# Calculate density function given distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**QUESTION**

The random variable X has de distribution function, $$F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2(1+x^{2})}, \: \: x< 0\\
\frac{1+2x^{2}}{2(1+x^{2})}, \: \: x\geq  0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Show that X is a continuous random variable and determine its density function.

**ANSWER**

So far I have tried to calculate the density function by calculating the derivatives of the two branches. That gave me: $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{-x}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}, \: \: x< 0\\
\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}, \: \: x\geq  0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Is this correct? What do I have to do next, to verify that X is a continuous random variable? Thanks.

Comment: You´re right, if you mean $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2(1+x^{2})}, \: \: x< 0 \\
\frac{1+2x^{2}}{2(1\color{red}+x^{2})}, \: \: x\color{red}{\geq } 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @callculus You are right I made a mistake copying the questions, It's edited now. Any suggestions on how to prove that X is a continuous random variable?

Comment: You can verify if $f(0^-)=f(0^+)$.

Comment: $F(x)$ is continuous (and differentiable) everywhere except possibly at $x=0$. So check continuity of $F(x)$ (_not_ $f(x)$ as suggested by @calculus) at $x=0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[A continuous random variable is a random variable whose cumulative distribution function is continuous everywhere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Continuous_random_variable)

So  $F(x)$ is a continues function or not?

Comment: How to check that $F'=f$?